# Central vs. local scheduler processes for luigi

Tags: luigi

I'm learning to pipeline with luigi, and this had me stuck for hours.  I had a simple task writing output to a local file.  Using the central scheduler to execute:

`python src/pipeline.py GetNeuronIDs --species drosophila\ melanogaster`

returns

> ```
> Did not run any tasks
> This progress looks :| because there were tasks that were not granted run permission by the scheduler
> ```

Finally, I tried using the local scheduler:

```
python src/pipeline.py GetNeuronIDs --species drosophila\ melanogaster --local-scheduler
```

and it ran fine, having created the local output file.  I gather this is due to write/ownership permissions?

I want to make sure my setup is as required per luigi workflow.  Did I miss a step in assigning permissions to luigi processes running central scheduler, or is it something else?
I invoked the luigi server like so:

```
luigid --background --logdir logs
```

And to clean up after, I had to do something like `ps ax |grep  luigid` to get the `PID`, then kill it.  Is this the right way to quit luigid?

Comment: show us your task

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the user which is running the `luigid` process has read and execute permissions on `src/pipeline.py`. Or make sure that the user which is running the `luigid` process belongs to the same group as the one that owns `src/pipeline.py`, and that the group permissions on `src/pipeline.py` are correct.

For more information on Linux file permissions, i've found this site to be a useful resource:
https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions